# RoR Savon : cannot authenticate since ruby 2.2.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, savon

I've tried many things but I'm not able to do it.
I used to work with savon in my app to access a soap webservice. While the app was using RoR 3 and ruby 1.9.3 I hadn't problem, but since I upgrade my app to use RoR5 and ruby 2.2.2 I'm not able to use it anymore.

When I try to request the soap server it tells me "Authentication is required".

I tried with basic auth :

```
    client = Savon.client(wsdl: uri, basic_auth: [user_login, user_password])
    call_response = client.call(:good_types, :message => {})
```

but also with custom headers :

```
    realm = Base64.strict_encode64("login:pass")
    client = Savon.client(
       wsdl: uri,
       soap_header: { 'Authorization:' => "Basic #{realm}"},
       log: true,
       log_level: :debug,
       pretty_print_xml: true
   )
   # call the 'getFood' operation
   response = client.call(:good_types, message: {})
```

but no one could helped me, always the same response : "Authentication is required"

Maybe someone know how to build pre-emptively auth ?

Answer (score 0):

I got it!

If someone has the same problem :

```
soap_header: { 'Authorization:' => "Basic #{realm}"}
```

is wrong cause the Authorization params is not for soap header but http header

So we have to use :

```
headers: { 'Authorization:' => "Basic #{realm}"}
```